# Pause before response page script is called [Chrome DevTools]

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-chrome-devtools

I have this HTML page but i dont want to access to server-side source code.
this page have a basic POST form and when it was succesfull submitted it reload the same page with the script **windows.location('someothersite.com');** on the head, so the script was immediatly launched.

it was a simple snippets

**BEFORE :**

```
 <form method="POST">
        <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

**AFTER SUCCESSFUL SUBMIT :**

```
<script>windows.location('someothersite.com');</script>
```

so, the server load the same page with this script inside (this is a really basic example just for make easyest to understand what's my issue)
and **i will be immediatly redirect** to 'someothersite.com'...

i want to **intercept and pause** the page before script was launched to **prevent the redirection.**

i tried to push F8 but nothing happened because the first page have not js inside and the second page **is too fastly to let me hit F8** or put some breackpoint on the source code.

I'm using google chrome 65.0 and i have also tried to slow the load on the network tab but nothing.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in chrome debugger or insert a `debugger` statement at the point in the script where you want to pause execution.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

You can also set a breakpoint on the `unload` event which occurs right before navigation. Go to `Sources -> Event Listener Breakpoints -> Load -> unload` in chrome dev tools.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#event-listeners

Enable "Preserve log upon navigation" in the console settings to keep the breakpoints across page loads:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#additional_settings

Comment: this is the entire source of that page, no script inside: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jjbev1gg/)where u suppose i have to put the breackpoint?

Comment: You may need to enable Preserve log upon navigation in the console settings.